# Django request transactions don't completely rollback after save() called.  TransactionMiddleware not behaving as expected

Tags: django, transactions, rollback

Following on from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196404/django-transactions-requests-fail-but-still-partially-commit), I'm using MySQL with an InnoDB engine and have set up a simple test table.  When I run the following code:

```
c.execute("""insert into test(text) values('test1')""")
conn.commit()
c.execute("""insert into test(text) values('test2')""")

# Raise an exception to simulate an error
raise Exception('spam', 'eggs')

c.execute("""insert into test(text) values('test3')""")
conn.commit()
```

I see an entry just for test1 in the database, as expected.

After creating the relevant model class and running the equivalent code in Django, (I have specified TransactionMiddleware in settings.py):

```
def transaction_test(request):
    t1 = Test(text='test1')
    t2 = Test(text='test2')
    t1.save()

    # Raise an exception to simulate an error
    raise Exception('spam', 'eggs')    

    t2.save()
    return render_to_response('index.html')
```

Then I still see an entry for 'test1' in the table, whereas I would have expected the  whole transaction to have rolled back, including the save of 'test1', as per the description given in the documentation for TransactionMiddleware

Has anybody else seen this?  Is there something other Django setting that I am missing?

Comment: where do you start the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Are you *sure* that the `test` table is using the innodb engine?

I could believe that you haven't set up the transaction middleware correctly, but if the `transaction.commit_on_success` decorator isn't working, it sounds to me like the table might be using `MyISAM`.

You can check the engine with the following command in the mysql shell:

```
show table status where name="test";
```

Comment: Yep - absolutely positive InnoDB is set up as the database engine.  That's why I included the snippet showing the raw SQL.   When I executed this code with a MyISAM engine, it committed two entries to the database; when I switched to InnoDB it only showed one entry, having rolled back the transaction.  However, trying to do the same with Django, it _always_ commits the save operation, regardless of which database engine I use.   I ran the SQL above anyway, and it clearly showed InnoDB as the engine for the "test" table

Comment: OK, I misread your raw SQL snippet the first time. I have one final idea. Django will create a table for the test model named `myapp_test`, not `test`. Are you testing the same table with the SQL and Django?

Comment: I did things the other way round:   first I created the table in the database (specifying innodb as the engine) and then ran inspectdb to generate the Django model.   In this case will Django still create another internal table somewhere that I need to track down (and check that it's using InnoDB)?

Comment: Here's the docs about [table names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#table-names). You can specify the table name that Django will use with the `db_table` meta option. `inspectdb` does appear to specify the db_table meta option correctly, so this might not be the problem.

Comment: I've just been through and set all the django tables to be innodb as well.  And verified the db_table meta-data.  But no good - the transaction still doesn't rollback after an exception

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django.test.TestCase as opposed to django.test.TransactionTestCase, then the whole operation is wrapped in a transaction which is rolled back; except that MySQL may commit  for example when locking tables, which confuses things. I resolved a similar problem by switching the superclass to TransactionTestCase.